# remove css comments with /*! in rails 3.2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, yui

Is it possible delete comments with `Yui compressor` or `Sass-rails` of comments with `/*!` an exclamation point before of any css line when I try precompile my assets?

I have tried for my production env with:

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
config.sass.line_comments = false
config.sass.cache = false
```

But it does not work

Thanks!

Comment: The /*! comments are usually used for licensing notices (which are legal requirements), it's unlikely that the compressors will provide a method for ignoring these

Comment: The problem is that I can not compress/minify this license comments. I want minify/compress these license comments if it's possible. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that a normal CSS compressor will do this, since the normal method for minifying is to strip out the comments altogether.  I think you'd probably either have to dive into the base code and make your own mods (probably not a good idea), or implement something yourself that processes the files after compression to remove \r\n from comments.  You could use something like https://github.com/reworkcss/rework to do this.  That said, I'm not sure that license comments are really going to cause you a big performance problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to somehow compress the css comments!